# ASP.NET(VB) Contact Mailer Form Error: MailObj.Send(myMessage) failed execution.

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sendmail

I am trying to get this contact form to work, but I get an error message saying: "failed to send message".  The problem is the section of code near the bottom of the page where it executes this line of code:

```
   MailObj.Send(myMessage)
```

I've put dummy credentials in the snippet below but triple-checked my smtp un/pw and cant figure things out.

**VB CODE**

```
Imports System.Web.Mail
Imports System.Net.Mail

Partial Class Contact
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub SubmitForm_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        If Not Page.IsValid Then Exit Sub

        Dim SendResultsTo As String = "myemail@email.com"
        Dim smtpMailServer As String = "stmp.mysite.com"
        Dim smtpUsername As String = "myusername"
        Dim smtpPassword As String = "mypassword"
        Dim MailSubject As String = "Customer Message"

        Try
            Dim txtQ As TextBox = Me.FormContent.FindControl("TextBoxQ")
            If txtQ IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim ans As String = ViewState("hf1")
                If ans.ToLower <> txtQ.Text.ToLower Or ans.ToUpper <> txtQ.Text.ToUpper Then
                    Me.YourForm.ActiveViewIndex = 3
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If

            Dim FromEmail As String = SendResultsTo
            Dim msgBody As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
            Dim sendCC As Boolean = False


            For Each c As Control In Me.FormContent.Controls
                Select Case c.GetType.ToString
                    Case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox"
                        Dim txt As TextBox = CType(c, TextBox)
                        If txt.ID.ToLower <> "textboxq" Then
                            msgBody.Append(txt.ID & ": " & txt.Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
                        End If
                        If txt.ID.ToLower = "email" Then
                            FromEmail = txt.Text
                        End If
                        If txt.ID.ToLower = "subject" Then
                            MailSubject = txt.Text
                        End If
                    Case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox"
                        Dim chk As CheckBox = CType(c, CheckBox)
                        If chk.ID.ToLower = "checkboxcc" Then
                            If chk.Checked Then sendCC = True
                        Else
                            msgBody.Append(chk.ID & ": " & chk.Checked & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
                        End If

                    Case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton"
                        Dim rad As RadioButton = CType(c, RadioButton)
                        msgBody.Append(rad.ID & ": " & rad.Checked & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
                    Case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList"
                        Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(c, DropDownList)
                        msgBody.Append(ddl.ID & ": " & ddl.SelectedValue & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
                End Select
            Next
            msgBody.AppendLine()

            msgBody.Append("Browser: " & Request.UserAgent & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
            msgBody.Append("IP Address: " & Request.UserHostAddress & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
            msgBody.Append("Server Date & Time: " & DateTime.Now & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)

            Dim myMessage As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
            myMessage.To.Add(SendResultsTo)
            myMessage.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(FromEmail)
            myMessage.Subject = MailSubject
            myMessage.Body = msgBody.ToString
            myMessage.IsBodyHtml = False
            If sendCC Then myMessage.CC.Add(FromEmail)


            Dim basicAuthenticationInfo As New System.Net.NetworkCredential(smtpUsername, smtpPassword)
            Dim MailObj As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(smtpMailServer)
            MailObj.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo

           'problem occurs here.  The error details state "Failure to send mail"
            MailObj.Send(myMessage)

            Me.YourForm.ActiveViewIndex = 1
        Catch
            Me.YourForm.ActiveViewIndex = 2
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

ASP.NET CODE

```
  <asp:MultiView ID="YourForm" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
            <asp:View ID="FormContent" runat="server">
                <label for="Email">
                    Enter your Email Address:<br />

                    <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" Columns="35">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </label>
                <%--make sure they enter an email--%>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
                    Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please enter your email address." SetFocusOnError="True"
                    CssClass="ValidateMessage" ForeColor="">* Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <%--<make sure its a valid email--%>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
                    ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid email address." SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
                    CssClass="ValidateMessage" ForeColor="">* Please enter a valid email address.</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                <br />
                <br />

                <label for="Message">
                    Please type your message below:
                    <%--make sure user enters a message--%>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Message"
                        ErrorMessage="Please enter a message" SetFocusOnError="True" CssClass="ValidateMessage"
                        ForeColor="">* Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <br />
                    <%-- text box that users can type their message--%>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Message" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="55" Rows="10">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </label>
                <br />
               <% %>
                <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="True"
                    ShowSummary="True" CssClass="ValidateMessage" ForeColor="" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <%-- submit button--%>
                <asp:Button ID="SubmitForm" runat="server" OnClick="SubmitForm_Click" Text="Submit Form" />
                <br />
            </asp:View>

            <asp:View ID="FormConfirmationMessage" runat="server">
                Your message has been sent. Thank you for contacting us. One of our dedicated staff
                members will contact you shortly.<br />
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View ID="FormErrorMessage" runat="server">
                We're sorry, there was an error sending your message. Please give us a call at 1-877-302-5604
                or email us at team@acupuncturepainpros.com.
            </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>
```

Comment: does the InnerException property of the Exception being thrown provide additional information?

Comment: That's a awful lot of code you want us to look at. Are you sure you can't narrow that down?

Comment: yeah...sorry, I guess that part of my post got cut by accident...the console report is "Fail Send Message"

Comment: i know its alot of code...I just wanted to show that the coding seems okay...except for the problem at the very end of the VB Code when it reaches the statement  MailObj.Send(myMessage).  I commented it with a "problem occurs" tag to help locate it.

Answer (score 2):

I exactly copied your code and used it to send a message to my own mail server. This looks like an issue with the server you're sending it to.

Are your trying to relay through an smtp server without the proper authentication/rules etc?

Remember, with most email servers, if you want to send email to an address they are not responsible for, you need to authenticate and have authorization to relay via that authentication.

--

Well, you can always look in the SMTP server logs (if you have access to them) in order to determine why you're message is failing to send.

Otherwise you can "manually" send an email to the server from the same machine your app is run from. This can tell you what the problem is.

So, you do this:

From the same machine your app is hosted at (and assuming we're dealing with windows here) Telnet to the mail server by running the following command:

```
telnet smtp.siteA.com 25
```

If you're running Win7 and don't want to turn on telnet you can use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) instead.

Once connected to the server you should see a welcome message of some sort. Then, type the following commands one per line ending each line with Enter.

```
EHLO example.com
MAIL FROM: <example@example.com>
RCPT TO: <admin@siteA.com>
DATA
Subject:Test Subject
Test Body
.
QUIT
```

Each of those commands should be responded to with an acknowledgement by the server. If there is a problem with one of them then you will be told as much.

If the response to the first line (the one with EHLO in it) has a problem then try:

```
HELO example.com
```

I've used example.com to represent a domain and address that the email is coming from by the way. That can be changed to whatever you like and generally won't matter all that much to the result.

This whole thing simulates the exact same process that will be happen when your code tries to send the email. If you're running from the same machine with the same variables such as server and address, then you should get the same results.

Comment: what if my the recipient is admin@siteA.com and the stmp is stmp.site@.com?  Shouldnt that work?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean you're sending an email to admin@siteA.com via the smtp server smtp.siteA.com. If that is the case then generally you would expect that server to be responsible for that address, in which case you are not relaying. That's what I meant when I said "if you want to send email to an address they are NOT responsible for". If you are trying to send to an address the server is responsible for, there are still other possibilities. Relaying is just the common gotcha issue for people. Are you sure the mailbox  you're sending to exists? That would cause it to fail as well.

Comment: Thanks for your insight man.  I really appreciate all the community help.  And you're right, I am sending it to an email address (that I've checked...it works)@siteA.com via the stmp server stmp.siteA.com.  But its still not working...any idea of where/what else I should be checking...I'm really stumped

Comment: I had a lot to say, so I just went ahead and updated the answer to include some additional troubleshooting steps for you.

Comment: that's some great examples man.  I'm going to troubleshoot right now.  Will post my results hopefully soon.